# Javascript function parameters in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf

Hopefully you all don't get pissed at me for such a seemingly simple question..

Basically, I have a PDF form that I'm scripting with javascript.

I have a bunch of check boxes that I would like to set required and/or not required based on other inputs and I'm trying to repeat code as little as possible, especially since there's a ton of inputs.

Right now, the best way I can accomplish what I'm attempting is by setting a function for each instance of inputs as follows:

```
function setWalkwayNotRequired() {
    this.getField("sidewalkAsphalt").required = false;
    this.getField("sidewalkConcrete").required = false;
    this.getField("sidewalkPavers").required = false;
    this.getField("sidewalkCondition").required = false;
}
```

I would then call this function based on the input of a certain checkbox:

```
if (this.getField("sidewalkNone").value == "Yes") {
    setSidewalkNotRequired();
}
```

Then all of the above-mentioned fields would be set to not required.

I feel like there should be a way to create a single "setRequired" or "setNotRequired" function to take a parameter of the field in question.

In my mind that would look something like this:

```
function setRequired(a, b, c, d) {
    this.getField(a).required = true;
    this.getField(b).required = true;
    this.getField(c).required = true;
    this.getField(d).required = true; 
}
```

I would then call on that function for all instances, for example, walkways (like that above) or driveways, etc. like so:

```
if (this.getField("sidewalkNone").value == "Off") {
   setRequired('"sidewalkAsphalt"', '"sidewalkConcrete"', '"sidewalkPavers"', '"sidewalkCondition"');
}
```

Again, in my mind what would then be output based on the above code once the function is called is something like:

```
if (this.getField("sidewalkNone").value == "Off") {
    this.getField("sidewalkAsphalt").required = true;
    this.getField("sidewalkConcrete").required = true;
    this.getField("sidewalkPavers").required = true;
    this.getField("sidewalkCondition").required = true;
}
```

Doing it the way I did in the first code block would require me to create separate functions for each set of checkboxes, creating a lot of code in an already huge file. The second way would allow me to use 1 function over and over throwing the field names as parameters depending on where I'm at in the PDF.

I'm also not very clear on if it's even legal to declare the parameters as I did with the '"..."' quotes; I did that because I need the double quotes inside the this.getField().

Again, I'm sorry if this is novice, I've just been trying to play with the code for a while now and can't get it to work.

Any input would be amazing.

Comment: Do you know what maximum version of ECMAScript is supported by the minimum version of Acrobat  / PDF you're targeting? Using ES2015+ features makes things easier, but won't be supported by older PDF viewers or older versions of Acrobat.

Comment: I do not, but I do know it doesn’t let you use let variables.

Comment: If it "it doesn’t let you use let variables" then it isn't JavaScript. Where did you figure that out?

Comment: It just doesn’t work when I tried. It’s definitely JS though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass in an `Array` of field names:

```
function setRequired( fieldNames, isRequired = true ) {

    for( var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++ ) {
        var fieldName = fieldNames[i];
        this.getField( fieldName ).required = isRequired;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if( this.getField("sidewalkNone").value == "Off" ) {
   setRequired( [ "sidewalkAsphalt", "sidewalkConcrete", "sidewalkPavers", "sidewalkCondition" ] );
}
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much, I knew it was something simple!

Answer (score 0):

If you use hierarchical naming with dot notation, you can set properties on the parent to affect all children. For example, if you name the fields "sidewalk.Asphalt", "sidewalk.Concrete", and "sidewalk.Pavers"...

```
this.getField("sidewalk").required = true;
```

... will set all the children to be required.

Comment: Interesting, that's very helpful as well. Thanks!!